# How to style horizontal custom scrollbar for a single image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, image, scrollbar

I want to style a hero with a single image that can be dragged/scrolled horizontally -

**here's a video showing the wanted reult:**
https://vimeo.com/720043179

Can anyone explain or refer me to a method to create such component?

I'm working on a project with Nextjs | React | Typescript | Tailwindcss

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thank you for your question.
I found that one slider matches your requirement.

Here is link [Paver](http://terrymun.github.io/paver/demo/index.html)